# How to use sonar.jdbc.password value from AWS SecretsManager when you install SonarQube in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, sonarqube, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to install SonarQube Community Edition version 10 on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance. According to the [installation instructions of SonarQube 10](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/install-the-server/), the `sonar.jdbc.username` and `sonar.jdbc.password` are stored in `<SONARQUBE_HOME>/conf/sonar.properties` file. I am trying to avoid storing the password in the clear text configuration file on the server. Instead, I would like to use a password/secret manager like AWS SecretsManager. The instance has access to the password in the SecretsManager. It can retrieve the password from the SecretsManager using AWS CLI or another AWS SDK, but how can I use that password to run SonarQube?